# Removing Chromium from Debian bullseye

Tags: debian, chrome, free-software

I use `apt dist-upgrade` and got the following message:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  chromium
The following packages have been kept back:
  phonon-backend-gstreamer-common sshfs
The following packages will be upgraded:
  chromium-common chromium-sandbox
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

I get about one week and when I use `apt update` frequently I see above message.

I'm worry, I hate `google chrome`. Does Debian want to remove `chromium`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are no plans to remove Chromium. There are however some transitions going on in testing just now that are affecting Chromium, and you might well be seeing the effects of that. Everything should sort itself out over the next couple of weeks.

Answer (score 2):

> Does Debian want to remove `chromium`?

To check which packages will be removed from Debian testing you can use the command `how-can-i-help` from the package with the same name. (With the `-a` option to display all packages).

Currently how-can-i-help shows the following opportunities for contribution:

- Packages where help is needed, including orphaned ones (from WNPP)
- Bugs suitable for new contributors (tagged 'newcomer')
- Bugs affecting Debian infrastructure (tagged 'newcomer')
- **Packages removed from Debian testing**
- **Packages going to be removed from Debian testing**